# Make callback in Vue

Tags: vue.js, callback

My vue widget works like this.
I use https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element to make embed widget to any webpage.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Foo Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <vue-widget>...</vue-widget>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My task is to make callback function in my app which can be triggered OUTSIDE `<vue-widget>...</vue-widget>`.
I tried this bit it don't work and I don't know why

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Foo Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <vue-widget>...</vue-widget>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
      vueWidget_onInitCallback = function() {
        console.log('foo')
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**App.vue:**

```
methods: {
  someFunction() {
    if (typeof vueWidget_onInitCallback == 'function') {
      vueWidget_onInitCallback();
    }
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.someFunction()
}
```

Comment: Try changing the order of the two `script` tags such that the function is defined before the code that checks for its existence

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

**index.html**

```
<script>
function vueWidget_onInitCallback () {
  console.log('plugin initiated');
}
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
methods: {
  someFunction() {
    function onInit(callback) {
      if (callback && typeof(callback) == "function") callback();
    }
    onInit(vueWidget_onInitCallback);
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.someFunction()
}
```

Everything works just fine.